# Cast child object to parent type for serialization

Tags: c#, serialization, casting

I need to be able to cast an instance of a child object to an instance of its parent object.

```c#
public class Parent 
{
    public string name{ get; set; } 
}

public class Child : Parent { }

var myClass = new Child();

(Parent)myClass;
```

The cast above doesn't seem to work, and the object still has child's type **when serialized**.

Is there another way to cast it?

I'm only using the child class for validation– I need the child to have *only* the parent's type for serialization reasons.

Comment: I need to do this as i am only using the child class for validation. I need the child to have only the parents type for serialisation reasons.

Comment: var castClass = (Parent)myClass 
castClass  still has Child type after this line.

Comment: This is a valid question, and the serializer exposes a behavior of C# that is not easy immediately obvious, that an object can be referenced as a base type, but casting it as such does not actually transform that object or its type.  This may work fine in most situations outside of serialization, but it is certainly not just about serialization.  

+1 for asking the question I was looking for.

However, editing your question a little would make it a more useful one.

Comment: Was almost about to ask this very question, though mine is `vb.net`. +1 to the question, because [Servy's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9082821/2410892) is what I've missed in every tries I've made (even tried serialization and found it too heavy) So +1 to Matt Grande's comment, because the question deserves **more precision** about the issue (serialization **and** Class usage) However, Servy's answer was not only about serialization (the secund paragraph exluding the quote isn't ;) ) Thanks, I'm now able to use my (parent) Class with **200+ `ReadOnly`** Properties.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> problem is the xml serialiser serialises the object with child type as
> root element. i dont really want to pass my target type all the way
> down into the serialiser. is there a better way? – Jules

I haven't worked with serialization much, but my guess is that you're going to need to alter your definition of "how do I serialize myself" in the child element to write itself out as if it was a parent.

If you want to actually have an instance of "Parent" then you'll need to create a *new* Parent and copy all of the values from the Child to that Parent (I wouldn't do this if you have a lot of them, but if you don't have *that* many then it shouldn't be a problem).

The easiest way to do this would be to make a copy constructor in Parent. It would be a constructor that takes a Parent as a parameter and copies the values (Name in this case, and I assume you may have omitted others) from the parameter to itself.

You can then make a new Parent, pass in the Child as the parameter (since a Child is a Parent, no cast/conversion is needed) and it will spit out an actual instance of Parent.

Answer (score 16):

You're not assigning the cast to anything.

```
var myClass = new Child();
Parent p = (Parent)myClass;
```

**Edit** - I think you misunderstand how casting works.  Say Parent has a `virtual` method, `DoStuff()` that is overridden in `Child`.  Even if you cast `myClass` to `Parent`, it's going to run the `Child`'s `DoStuff` method.  No matter what, that `Child` is a `Child`, and will always be a `Child`, even if you cast it.

If you're trying to pass it to a method that accepts a `Parent` object, you don't have to cast it.  It's already a `Parent`, by virtue of being a `Child`.

I think we're missing something.  What are you trying to accoplish?  What's not working?

Answer (score 13):

That should work.

But I suspect from the way you've written your code that you haven't captured the cast object in a new variable? Try this:

```
var myClass = new Child()
var myClassAsParent = (Parent)myClass;
// myClassAsParent still has the type "Child", but can be accessed as if it were a Parent.
```

**Edit** 
Based on some of the comments you've been leaving, I believe you misunderstand a fundamental aspect of most programming languages. It is this: *the Type of an object cannot change*. An object that was instantiated as a `Child` object *will always be a `Child` object*.

Casting does not change the type of an object. Casting changes the way the rest of the program "sees" the object. It changes the interface of the object, if you will. So if you cast a `Child` object to a `Parent` type, the rest of the program thinks it's dealing with a `Parent` type, but it's *really* dealing with a `Child` type that is, to use a really bad analogy, dressed up in its parent's clothing.

In short, Casting doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: was an incomplete sample. 
this doesnt work 
var myClassAsParent = (Parent)myClass;

Comment: Randolpho: Can you please provide some additional information or an article where I can learn more about the "Type of an object cannot change.." logic and how it does/doesn't relates to casting. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I'm about five years late here, but...

You can use [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) to solve your problem.

Just define a mapping between the parent and child classes. The simplest map will do. In the class where you define your mappings:

```
CreateMap<Child, Parent>();
```

Then, at any point in your code, you could do:

```
Child child = new Child();
Parent parent = Mapper.Map<Parent>(child);
```

And your `parent` object will be a pure `Parent` with none of the `child` object properties.

As others have said, casting an object will preserve its type. That only changes the pointer. But AutoMapper creates a new instance of the target type and copies values from the parameter to the instance of the target type, matching properties by name.

Answer (score 2):

you could use the as operator... nice thing about THAT is no exception will be thrown and you can check for null if the "cast" fails.

```
public class Parent 
{
 public string name{get;set;} 
}

public class child : Parent{}

var myClass = new Child()
Parent foo  = myClass as Parent
if ( foo == null ) Debug.WriteLine("foo is NOT of type Parent");
```

Answer (score 2):

If `Parent` is a superclass of `Child`, then automatically a `Child` is also a `Parent` (contains all properties & methods of `Parent) and you don't need to cast.

Also, you cannot just start a line with a cast. You could write for example

```
Parent p = (Parent)myClass;
```

Answer (score 1):

Having just hit a variation of the problem, I think I've got a non-serialization based solution.

Like the OP, I have Class B that inherits from Class A, and I need B.GetType().Name to return as if it was Class A.

On Class B, you need to override GetType() to return .GetType().BaseType

That way  B.GetType() will always look like A.GetType()

As that's rather heavy handed, and all my classes inherit from my own standard baseClass, I'm going to add a property called TypeName to the baseClass that returns this.GetType().Name

Then on my one special class that I want to look like it's parent, I'll override it to return this.GetType().BaseType.Name

Then in my code, I'll reference .TypeName instead of doing .GetType().Name directly when I need the special "masking" of the class's type name to kick in.  Given that I'm only using .GetType() in the one area where I need to ignore this child class, it's fairly clean for my own use.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and came up with the following solution:

My initial code was thus:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Person() {};
    public Person( Person rhs ) 
    {
        Name = rhs.Name;
    }
}

public class Customer : Person
{
    private string m_role = "Customer";
    public string Role { get m_role; }

    public Customer() : base();
}

public class Employee : Person
{
    private string m_role = "Employee";
    public string Role { get m_role; }

    public Employee() : base();
}
```

and when I tried casting a Person object to a customer I got "cast fail" errors

Rather than pursuing the idea of casting I decided to modify the Child's copy  constructors, thus:

```
public class Customer : Person
{
    private string m_role = "Customer";
    public string Role { get m_role; }

    public Customer() : base();
    public Customer( Person per ) : base( per);
}

public class Employee : Person
{
    private string m_role = "Employee";
    public string Role { get m_role; }

    public Employee () : base();
    public Employee ( Person per) : base( per);
}
```