# Why Virtual Method of Derived Class is not able to be use

Tags: c#, oop

First of all, although the code shown below contains Entity Framework, this question is completely related to OOP and C#.

I have a class derived from `DbContext`, having virtual property `haberler` and a derived class `MyDbContext` derived from `DbContext`.

```
public class HaberContext : DbContext
  {
     public virtual DbSet<Haber> haberler { get; set; }
  }

public class Haber { }
```

---

Instanting MyClass with like `haberler`

```
DbContext context = new HaberContext();  // [ERROR]
```

with like this even if using `new HaberContext()`;
prevent me to use the virtual property named `haberler`

> Error  1   `System.Data.Entity.DbContext` does not contain a definition for `haberler` and no extension method `haberler` accepting a first argument of type `System.Data.Entity.DbContext` could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   c:\csharpprojects\entitycodefirst\entityframework-haberportal\gui.cs
>   37 27  EntityFrameWork-HaberPortal

Notice that `DbContext` is the base class of `HaberContext`

I have to instantiate the `MyDbContext` with:

```
HaberContext context = new HaberContext(); // [OK]
```

Or with Implicitly Typed Local Variable like this:

```
var context = new HaberContext();  // [OK]
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about what you mean in those bold text.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I removed my spaghetti sentence after 5 months :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a casting issue, and has to to with the run-time vs. the compiler-time identity of variable `context`.

When you declare `DbContext context`, you're creating a variable. No matter what goes in that variable, the compiler only knows of it as a `Dbcontext`. This may be a `HaberContext` at runtime, but it's still only `DbContext` at compile time, so the compiler can't attach methods or properties from `HaberContext`.

There are several ways in which this can be a good thing, such as being able to reassign `context` later in your control flow, or exposing properties/methods as a type which is implemented by a nonpublic type (both the `Type` class and `IEnumerable` interface make use of this under the hood in .NET)

Answer (score 1):

If you are instantiating a class you must have the stored datatype being the "youngest", but if you can still access the child type as a parent type, however you will loose access to child specific methods.
You must cast this from an instantiated object though.

```
DbContext context = new HaberContext(); //will not work

HaberContext Hcontext = new HaberContext();
var context = (DbContext)Hcontext; //cast done
```

But even though you will be able to access context as a DbContect object in this case, it will still have the type of HarberContext.

Refer to this post for more info: [cast child object as parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9082011/cast-child-object-as-parent)